# Paypal profile sharing Consent in android gives invalid_request error

Tags: android, paypal

While integrating profile sharing consent with ***paypal*** getting below error:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid scope requested"}
```

When using `CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT=PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX`.

Comment: are you getting the same error for other environments as well?

Comment: Any update on this??? I am getting this issue.